# How to filter files based on tag on OSX under a folder

Tags: macos, file-management, finder

In the finder, I can easily tag a file and access all files with a certain tag from the sidebar. However, is there any way to find all files with a certain tag **under a given folder**? Otherwise, I have to create a new tag for each folder to implement this functionality, which is still cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually super easy to do (although not obvious at first!). Go to the folder you want to search and type a space in the search bar. This is to get the search options. Make sure you change the search scope to your `folder` not `This Mac`. There is a little bar that appears saying `Search:`.

Next click the `+` button on the right side to add a search condition. Click the criteria selection (usually `Name` by default). Select `Other` and then choose `tag`. Then type the tag name and vola you have your search results!

Alternatively you can also just type `tag: blue` or whatever the tag is on your computer. I just learned this one myself. Take a look [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh15155/mac) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly. I am really surprised that the finder have all those functions under the hood :D